# How to reference an object array item using string?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array

```
fruit={sweet:'apple',dry:{f1:'raisin',f2:'almond'},sour:'strawberry'}
```

it contains simple and nested objects as items

i can reference f1 using bracket notation like `fruit[0]["dry"]["f1"]`
but i have a string variable that has the value `var str="dry.f1"`

value of `"str"` changes on runtime it could be `"sweet"` or `"dry.f1"` or `"sour"`

how do i reference the array item using `"str"`
if the value of str is either "`sweet"` or `"sour"` `fruit[str]` works fine

we can get the value of f1 using `fruit[0].dry.f1` but i need to access it using the variable str

Comment: Really simple way is use lodash library which has `get()` method that will take your string as input and return nested values by parsing internally

Comment: I'd also like to point out that this is usually not the right structure of JSON for such data. It should rather be something like `fruit={sweet:'apple',dry:['raisin', 'almond'],sour:'strawberry'}`

Comment: @sid-m what is wrong with the structure?

Comment: Note that what you've shown doesn't include an array, though your `fruit[0]["dry"]["f1"]` implies the object shown is in an array that isn't shown. @sid-m - that's not JSON.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `split` and `reduce`:

```js
var fruit={sweet:'apple',dry:{f1:'raisin',f2:'almond'},sour:'strawberry'};

var str1 = "dry.f1";
var str2 = "sweet";

var example1 = str1.split('.').reduce((a, b) => a[b], fruit);
var example2 = str2.split('.').reduce((a, b) => a[b], fruit);

console.log(example1);
console.log(example2);
```

This will **[split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split)** your string on each dot into an array, and then **[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** the fruit array by iterating through the values from the string, applying them to the fruit array, to get the value you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Chava, Ur solution worked. Will it affect the performance if the array has many rows and this is being used inside for loop to iterate through each row?

Answer (score 0):

Given array:

```
fruit={sweet:'apple',dry:{f1:'raisin',f2:'almond'},sour:'strawberry'}
```

And your string:

```
var str="dry.f1"
```

To lookup value `fruit.dry.f1` you essentially need to write a parser for `"dry.f1"`

There are plenty of libraries out there that solve this. I give an example below.

## AngularJS

Examples of such parsers exist e.g. angular 1.x's `$parse`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse

```
var getter = $parse('dry.f1');
var setter = getter.assign;
var context = {sweet:'apple',dry:{f1:'raisin',f2:'almond'},sour:'strawberry'}

expect(getter(context)).toEqual('raisin');
```

## Lodash

Lodash has a `get` method: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get

Answer (score 0):

You could make a conditional, `if` statement that checks if the string has a dot using `str.indexOf('.')` and do either

```
fruit[str]
```

Or

```
fruit[str1][str2]
```

Comment: I have done this as a workaround but i want to know if there is a better way of handling this

Comment: Feel free to mark it as the right way anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a value in an object given it's path, we must write a function that searches for that value path inside of the object.

Using `split` and `reduce`, we use `split` to break the path into an array of values that were dot-separated in the path (i.e. `"dry.f1"` becomes `["dry", "f1"]`). We then use `reduce` to iterate over these values in the array, getting deeper into the object in each iteration until we have our value:

```
function findValueByPath(obj, path) {

    return path.split(".").reduce(function(objSoFar, currPath) {

        return objSoFar[currPath];

    }, obj);
}
```

For example, `findValueByPath( {a: { b: 5 } } , "a.b")` returns 5.

[Click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to read more about [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). 
[Click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to read more about [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

As a side note, this problem is commonly implemented by libraries such as Lodash, which has the function `get` that does exactly this ([click here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) for `get` documentation in Lodash).